# How to get user ID from the profile page and plug into id= in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, profile, user-data

I am working on a frustrating project and need help. I need to get the $user_id from the profile page that is being viewed and plug that value into a shortcode's id = "_" $atts field. I am using ultimate member as my membership plugin. The shortcode I need to plug the $user_id into is as follows...

`echo do_shortcode( '[aiovg_user_videos id=" '.$user_id.' "]' ); }`

The shortcode is going onto a profile tab called "Videos" that will have the user's videos they upload and import. What I have come up with so far, though it hasn't worked is as follows...

```
add_filter('um_profile_tabs', 'videos_tab', 1000 );
function videos_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['videos'] = array(
        'name' => 'Videos',
        'icon' => 'um-icon-ios-videocam',
        'custom' => true
    );  
    return $tabs;
}

/* Tell the tab what to display */

// If is current user's profile (profile.php)
if ( defined('IS_PROFILE_PAGE') && IS_PROFILE_PAGE ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
// If is another user's profile page
} elseif (! empty($_GET['user_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['user_id']) ) {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

echo do_shortcode( "[aiovg_user_videos id=" . $user_id . "]" ); }
```

I'm not a coder, but I'm learning, so I really don't know what else I need to make this happen. I've tried many many things that have given me error after error. Simply put, I want to have the shortcode grab the user id from the user profile that is being viewed so i can display the shortcode with the id filled in automatically.

UPDATE:

Here is the original code from the videos.php file in the plugin...

```
     * Run the shortcode [aiovg_user_videos].
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @param array $atts An associative array of attributes.
     */
    public function run_shortcode_user_videos( $atts ) {    
        $user_slug = get_query_var( 'aiovg_user' );
        $content   = '';        

        if ( empty( $user_slug ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
                $user_slug = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', (int) $atts['id'] ); 
            } elseif ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $user_slug = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', get_current_user_id() );             
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $user_slug ) ) {      
            $attributes = shortcode_atts( $this->get_defaults(), $atts );
            $attributes['user_slug'] = $user_slug;

            $content = $this->get_content( $attributes );       
        }

        if ( empty( $content ) ) {
            $content = aiovg_get_message( 'videos_empty' );
        }

        return $content;    
    }
```

What it does, is pull the nicename from the post's author, so when you click on the author's name, it adds it to the end of this url: https://hairbowtutorials.com/user-videos/NICENAME. 
But if you add the id to the shortcode, you can put it on any page and it will show the videos from that person. I want to add this shortcode to the profile pages and have the id fill in automatically depending on which profile it is on. I'm not sure if it's possible, or if i need to make a whole new shortcode. But this is what the developer gave me...

"You simply need to use the following template function and build the shortcode dynamically,

```
<?php
$member_user_id = 1;
echo do_shortcode( "[aiovg_user_videos id=" . $member_user_id . "]" );
?>
```

You just need to find the member profile user id and store it in the $member_user_id variable."

UPDATE 2:
Here is what Ultimate Member uses to get the posts from the person's profile. I think I can set it up in a similar way...

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    //Only for AJAX loading posts
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            UM()->get_template( 'profile/posts-single.php', '', array( 'post' => $post ), true );
        }
    }
} else {
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) { ?>
        <div class="um-ajax-items">

            <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                UM()->get_template( 'profile/posts-single.php', '', array( 'post' => $post ), true );
            }

            if ( $count_posts > 10 ) { ?>
                <div class="um-load-items">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="um-ajax-paginate um-button" data-hook="um_load_posts"
                       data-author="<?php echo esc_attr( um_get_requested_user() ); ?>" data-page="1"
                       data-pages="<?php echo esc_attr( ceil( $count_posts / 10 ) ); ?>">
                        <?php _e( 'load more posts', 'ultimate-member' ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="um-profile-note">
            <span>
                <?php if ( um_profile_id() == get_current_user_id() ) {
                    _e( 'You have not created any posts.', 'ultimate-member' );
                } else {
                    _e( 'This user has not created any posts.', 'ultimate-member' );
                } ?>
            </span>
        </div>

    <?php }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem to execute the shortcode anywhere in particular. It sets a tab (or tries to) using the filter to return it, but it's not clear how the shortcode is supposed be added to the page content (under the tab). So, presumably there is or will be some kind of page template or function somewhere where that might happen.

Comment: (I'd look first in UM documentation, I think.).

Comment: I started thinking about that yesterday. I am going to try to put the code into the videos.php template. That's where this shortcode template is. I'll do a little more research, but the biggest thing I wanted to know is how to automate the ID if the shortcode is on a profile page only. If the person is logged in and it's their profile, it should show their own videos. If it's someone else's profile, it should grab the id from that profile.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused: You say you're encountering "errors." What kind of errors? If the functions aren't actually placed in the target content, by whatever means, how would they get - or GET - the right $user_id? And how would you know whether it's working or not?

Comment: Maybe it will help if I show you the original code and explain it better. I will add it as an edit to this question...

Comment: (it's the second half of the code example at that page that seems to answer the question from earlier...)

Comment: https://hairbowtutorials.com/user/lindabenefield/?profiletab=videos             This is the URL where the videos will be and where the shortcode will be. The id spot in the shortcode should pull the id from the profile it is on. Maybe it could get the id from the username in the url?

Comment: I'd recommend trying it with that code you used in your original example that currently stands outside of any function call. If it's not quite right, then will need to do some debugging.

Comment: Belay that!  Look at the code from the UM doc linked above... In the second function, for insertion of content, it uses the function um_profile_id() to get a profile id. On the other hand, I haven't looked at it closely (and can't test, because I don't have UM). There would, yes, be other ways to get the profile user ID if that doesn't do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you! I am sure I will eventually figure it out. If i knew how to just query the custom post type "aiovg_videos" with a filter for getting the current profile's user id, it could work perfectly. But i'm still learning how to write code from scratch like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!!! Here's what FINALLY worked!!

```
/**
 * Add a new Profile tab
 * @param array $tabs
 * @return array
 */
function um_videos_add_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs[ 'videos' ] = array(
        'name'   => 'Videos',
        'icon'   => 'um-icon-ios-videocam',
        'custom' => true
    );

    UM()->options()->options[ 'profile_tab_' . 'videos' ] = true;

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', 'um_videos_add_tab', 1000 );

/**
 * Render tab content
 * @param array $args
 */
function um_profile_content_videos_default( $args ) {
    /* START. You can paste your content here, it's just an example. */

    $action = 'videos';

$member_user_id = um_get_requested_user();
echo do_shortcode( "[aiovg_user_videos id=" . $member_user_id . "]" );


    /* END. You can paste your content here, it's just an example. */
}
add_action( 'um_profile_content_videos_default', 'um_profile_content_videos_default' );
```

Comment: Congratulations. It did turn out to be pretty simple after all.

Answer (score 0):

So it might be as simple as this:

```
//very close to your initial code
add_filter( 'um_profile_tabs', 'um_videos_tab', 1000 );

function um_videos_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['videos'] = array(
        'name' => 'Videos',
        'icon' => 'um-icon-ios-videocam',
        'custom' => true
    ) ;  

    return $tabs ;

}

//profile tab content
//based on how it appears UM has set up its action hooks
add_action( 'um_profile_content_videos', 'um_profile_content_videos' ) ;

function um_profile_content_videos() {

   //got to watch the apostrophes vs quotes so things don't get mixed up
   echo do_shortcode( ' [aiovg_user_videos id="' . um_profile_id() . '"] ' ) ; 

}
```

My uncertainty is based in part on the fact that I don't have either UM or whatever is producing the aiovg_user_videos shortcode, so can't test or debug. Given that I'm flying a little blind, my next try before digging into the UM code in detail would be to add `_default` to the "tag" and the "handler" in the `add_action` statement - so `add_action( 'um_profile_content_videos_default', 'um_profile_content_videos_default' ) ;` just in case that's a requirement for these hooks.